Keldysh rotation and Langreth theorem
Given a (Green) function of two time arguments on the Keldysh contour $g(\tau_1, \tau_2)$, we can distinguish between four cases, depending on whether each contour time lies on the forward or reverse branch of the contour. By arranging all four scenarios into a 2x2 matrix with normal time arguments, all the information of $g$ is captured.
\begin{align*}
g(\tau_1, \tau_2) \sim \begin{pmatrix}
g^{++}(t_1, t_2) & g^{+-}(t_1, t_2) \\
g^{-+}(t_1, t_2) & g^{--}(t_1, t_2) 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
If e.g. $g$ is a single-particle electron Green function, these components are commonly given names, such as chronological, anti-chronological, lesser and greater.
\begin{align*}
g^{++} &= g^c \\ 
g^{+-} &= g^< \\
g^{-+} &= g^> \\
g^{--} &= g^{\bar{c}}
\end{align*}
By definition, there is another condition or constraint relating to the four components.
\begin{align*}
g^{c} + g^{\bar{c}} = g^< + g^>
\end{align*}
Going further, there are also the (a)dvanced, (r)etarded and (k)eldysh versions of the Green function.
\begin{align*}
g^r &\equiv g^c - g^< \\
g^a &\equiv -g^{\bar{c}} + g^<\\
g^k &\equiv g^c + g^{\bar{c}}
\end{align*}
According to this report by Špička et al., there is a nice trick called the Keldysh rotation to convert between the various components.
\begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
        g^r & g^k \\
        0 & g^a
    \end{pmatrix} 
    &= \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        1 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        g^t & g^< \\
        -g^> & -g^{\bar{t}}
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        1 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}^T \\
  \begin{pmatrix}
        g^r & g^< \\
        0 & g^a
    \end{pmatrix} 
    &= \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        g^t & g^< \\
        -g^> & -g^{\bar{t}}
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\end{align*}
By multiplying two of these matrices in the upper triangular form, it appears that we have Langreth's Theorem (Haug & Jauho). Why is this possible?
\begin{align*}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        f^r & f^< \\
        0 & f^a
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        g^r & g^< \\
        0 & g^a
    \end{pmatrix} 
    = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
        f^r g^r & f^r g^< + f^< g^a \\
        0 & f^a g^a
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Since the upper triangular matrices are obtained by a similar transformation, it seems that we should redefine $g^>$ and $g^{\bar{c}}$ with a negative sign to have this nice matrix multiplication property.
